# How to select highest paid employee in dept based on the following?

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

Employees

```
EmpID | EmpName |EmpSalary | DEpartment
```

and then another table

Bonuses

```
EmpID |EmpBonus
```

How is it possible to get the highest paid employees per department including their bonus?

Comment: an example record and a sample query should also be posted along with the question for a `13k` user.

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using SQL-Server, use `ROW_NUMBER` or `DENSE_RANK`(if you want to include ties):

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT e.EmpID,e.EmpName,e.EmpSalary, e.Department,b.EmpBonus,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Department 
                               ORDER BY (EmpSalary + COALESCE(EmpBonus,0)) DESC)
    FROM Employees e LEFT OUTER JOIN Bonuses b
       ON e.EmpID = b.EmpID 
)
SELECT EmpID, EmpName, EmpSalary, Department, EmpBonus
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

[**Ranking Functions**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Comment: you should be using `LEFT JOIN` here, there might be a possibility that an employee has the highest salary but without a bonus.

Comment: @491243 An employee may even have more than 1 bonuses (the OP has not declared either that `EmpID` is the primary key in `Bonuses` table) But this answer covers what has been asked so far. +1

Comment: @491243: edited my answer accordingly. Thanks for the note.

Comment: @ypercube i also agree with this answer. but hopefully the rdbms of the OP supports window function. `+1 :)`

Answer (score -1):

In SQL Server

```
SELECT top 1 e.EmpID,e.EmpName,e.Department,
sum(EmpSalary + EmpBonus) as total_salary
FROM Employees e INNER JOIN Bonuses b
ON e.EmpID = b.EmpID 
group by e.EmpID,e.EmpName,e.Department
order by total_salary desc
```

In MySQL

```
SELECT e.EmpID,e.EmpName,e.Department,
sum(EmpSalary + EmpBonus) as total_salary
FROM Employees e INNER JOIN Bonuses b
ON e.EmpID = b.EmpID 
group by e.EmpID,e.EmpName,e.Department
order by total_salary desc limit 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select EmpID (EmpSalary+EmpBonus) as total_salary
from Employees e LEFT JOIN Bonuses b
order by total_salary desc
limit 1
```

I don't know which SGBD you're using so the limit 1 may be wrong. Do it how it works for your case.