# Adding row from two tables and union the two tables to get top 4 paying high fee

Tags: sql, database

I am having two tables with same column names(studentName, fee) from the two tables I want to add one row from both the tables i.e., the row having studenName as 'KAY'(shown in the below image) and get the top 4 students who are paying the high fee.

How to write a SQL Query to get my required output as the image shown below.

[image]

Comment: This looks like homework. Have you tried anything so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select highest paid employee in dept based on the following?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845510/how-to-select-highest-paid-employee-in-dept-based-on-the-following)

Comment: @SAL Duplicate for the reason why to close the question - yes..

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal who closed?I didnt close system treat as close i just marked as duplicate.Even i draw by flag

Comment: @SAL Nobody, I only wanted to say, that both of the questions lack any effort to solve a simple problem. Otherwise I do not think that those questions are duplicates.